# How can I convert an MDB (Access) file to MySQL (or plain SQL file)?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, import, dump

Is it possible to create a Dump of SQL commands from a Microsoft Access database? I hope to convert this MDB file into a MySQL database for importing so I don't have to go through the CSV step.

I would expect even an MSSQL dump file to still contain workable SQL commands, but I know nothing of MSSQL, please let me know.

Answer (score 72):

You want to convert mdb to mysql (direct transfer to mysql or mysql dump)?

Try a software called [Access to MySQL](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php).

> **Access to MySQL** is a small program that will convert Microsoft Access Databases to MySQL.
>
> - Wizard interface.
> - Transfer data directly from one server to another.
> - Create a dump file.
> - Select tables to transfer.
> - Select fields to transfer.
> - Transfer password protected databases.
> - Supports both shared security and user-level security.
> - Optional transfer of indexes.
> - Optional transfer of records.
> - Optional transfer of default values in field definitions.
> - Identifies and transfers auto number field types.
> - Command line interface.
> - Easy install, uninstall and upgrade.

See the aforementioned link for a step-by-step tutorial with screenshots.

Comment: update: the've crippled down the free version. search&replace works for smaller migrations though..

Comment: It works for the new .accdb Access format by the way

Comment: Just add that, current version of the program do not operates properly (at least that is what i was able to conclude). It is not dumping file properly (causing a lot of errors when you want to import) and direct connect to the database (even on the localhost) is not working.

Comment: If you have 64 bit OS, you will need a 32 bit ODBC driver. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Comment: @blackandorangecat I got around that by saving the Access file as a `*.mdb` (Access 2000-2003) file via the "Save and Publish" menu.

Comment: FYI: [This is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407659/2873538)

Answer (score 55):

If you have access to a linux box with mdbtools installed, you can use this Bash shell script (save as mdbconvert.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

TABLES=$(mdb-tables -1 $1)

MUSER="root"
MPASS="yourpassword"
MDB="$2"

MYSQL=$(which mysql)

for t in $TABLES
do
    $MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS $MDB -e "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $t"
done

mdb-schema $1 mysql | $MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS $MDB

for t in $TABLES
do
    mdb-export -D '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -I mysql $1 $t | $MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS $MDB
done
```

To invoke it simply call it like this:

```
./mdbconvert.sh accessfile.mdb mysqldatabasename
```

It will import all tables and all data.

Comment: Thanks a million for that script. Just two hints, I guess you can remove the `AWK` and `GREP` vars and I've added the options `-b strip -H` to `mdb-export` because I had some strange OLE objects in mdb and because the headers are loaded before. I guess in some cases `-b octal` would work as well but I had trouble with the binary data when loading it into mysql.

Comment: I'm importing tables with spaces in the name, and this didn't work for me. I had to add `IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")` after the shebang.

Comment: Awesome! managed to export MDB to MySQL on Mac. the only thing I stumbled was Table names with spaces, but fixed by putting: 

$MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS $MDB -e "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \`$t\`" 
and
mdb-export -D '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -I mysql $1 "$t" | $MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS $MDB
And, unfortunately, having to create an array with table names since 'for t in $TABLES' tokenizes by space.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi... I'm trying to get this to work with a database that has % symbols in the names. I'm new to MySQL, but it looks like those are a wildcard for string matching. Any ideas on how to escape them? `\%` and `\\%` aren't doing it for me...

Comment: `{ echo ‘set autocommit=0;’; mdb-export ... ;echo ‘commit;’ } | mysql ` may be faster

Comment: Thanks for this. For those on windows, I was able to get something going based on your script and the work by the champions at the [mdbtools-win](https://github.com/lsgunth/mdbtools-win) project.

Answer (score 46):

I modified the script by Nicolay77 to output the database to stdout (the usual way of unix scripts) so that I could output the data to text file or pipe it to any program I want. The resulting script is a bit simpler and works well.

Some examples:

```
./mdb_to_mysql.sh database.mdb > data.sql

./mdb_to_mysql.sh database.mdb | mysql destination-db -u user -p
```

Here is the modified script (save to mdb_to_mysql.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
TABLES=$(mdb-tables -1 $1)

for t in $TABLES
do
    echo "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $t;"
done

mdb-schema $1 mysql

for t in $TABLES
do
    mdb-export -D '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -I mysql $1 $t
done
```

Comment: Thanks, @mikkom and @Nicolay77! I created a Gist after copy-paste from here to CLI was a pain: https://gist.github.com/togume/83b4bf40e1528742374bbce338270f34

Comment: Can you convert this script into batch script?

Comment: Thank you for this, it pointed me in the right direction. I used the script below [1] to export to CSV files, although I ran into some issues with xargs on OSX and found this soution [2]    [1] - https://gist.github.com/ahmedelq/194718e6df95402663cb31a2be1ac212   [2] - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74457357/1398096

Answer (score 13):

OSX users can follow by **Nicolay77** or **mikkom** that uses the [**mdbtools**](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/mdbtools#default) utility. You can install it via **[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)**. Just have your homebrew installed and then go

```
$ brew install mdbtools
```

Then create one of the scripts described by the guys and use it. I've used mikkom's one, converted all my mdb files into sql.

```
$ ./to_mysql.sh myfile.mdb > myfile.sql
```

(which btw contains more than 1 table)

Comment: Newer versions of macOS/Homebrew the command is `brew install mdbtools`

Comment: mdbtools does not properly escape slashes unfortunately and does not appear to be maintained: https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools/issues/89

Comment: As @JohnMellor mentions, I also get the following error: `ERROR at line xxxx: Unknown command '\"'.` I could solve it by replacing  all the `\""` occurrences for `\"` and that did the trick.