# Windows command-line utility to convert Access .mdb database to MySQL or SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ms-access, command-line

Is there any program that can convert an Access .mdb database to a MySQL or SQL Server database by command line so I can use it and enter the required command line from my application?

Comment: Enter the command line from your application?  Sounds like you want to do this more than once.

Comment: yes , exactly and the mdb file sometimes be big about 1 giga and i want to access the resulted my sql file remotely from android app through jdbc "and i know the method " , this is what i want

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following links to convert mdb file to mysql file format

[How to import an Access MDB format database to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809654/how-to-import-an-access-mdb-format-database-to-mysql)

[How can I convert an MDB (Access) file to MySQL (or plain SQL file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722544/how-can-i-convert-an-mdb-access-file-to-mysql-or-plain-sql-file)

http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php

Comment: thanks for help but i tried those actually and i need command line feature in free program

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Migration Assistant has command line options. See the following link.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2010/09/09/performing-database-migration-assessment-using-ssma-console-application.aspx?Redirected=true