# How do I work around MacOS X not having xargs -d?

Tags: linux, macos, xargs

I have the following command:

```sh
xargs -d '\n' -n 8 bash -c 'phpcs_element PSR2 "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8"' -- >&2 2>/dev/null
```

If I run this command into Linux it will work, if I try to run in into Mac OSX will not because the OSX xargs doesn't know about xargs -d (delimiter).

```
xargs: illegal option -- d
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements] [-S replsize]]
             [-J replstr] [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs]
             [-s size] [utility [argument ...]]
```

Have anyone found a workaround for this issue?

Xargs Version: src/usr.bin/xargs/strnsubst.c,v 1.7 2004/10/18 15:40:47

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Please paste error messages as text instead of using screenshots. And note that you need a fence of triple backticks to be on its own line for it to behave right.

Comment: BTW, are you sure`>&2 2>/dev/null` is what you want? It _first_ copies the original stderr file descriptor to stdout, and _then_ makes stderr go to /dev/null -- so in the end, stdout still gets written (but to stderr), and stderr doesn't get written at all. If what you really want is _neither_ stdout or stderr to be written, you need to do those same operations in the opposite order: `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `-0` instead (making the NUL character the delimiter), and convert your newlines to NULs (which are what you ought to be using to separate items in a list of file names in the first place: the NUL, not the newline, is the only character that cannot exist in a file name).

```
tr '\n' '\0' |
  xargs -0 -n 8 bash -c 'phpcs_element PSR2 "${@:1:8}"' -- >&2 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have Homebrew, you can install `findutils` with this command:

```
brew install findutils
```

Then, you will be able you use `-d`.

You just have to prepend `xargs` with a `g` (making it `gxargs`).

Reference: https://superuser.com/a/467284/529605